# Keeping Andal picture or Photo

Tags: belief, alwar

It is commonly said that Bhoodevi [Andal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andal)'s independent picture or photo should not be kept and worshipped in the house. It is not a opinion based. Are there any puranical evidences pertaining to this?

Comment: Andal was born a long time after the writing of the Puranas. So, there will not be any Puranical evidences for not Keelung a picture of Andal...

Comment: When you ask such questions, you should also post the concerned photo.

Answer (score 2):

The Gurupamparai Prabhavam of Pinpazhagiya Perumal Jeeyar describes how Andal was found in a Tulasi garden which was maintained by Perialwar on Adi-Puram. It goes on to state that her birth was at the beginning of Kaliyuga.

Her sacred compositions, Nachiyar Thirumozhi and Thiruppavai have been included by Nathamunigal in the Nalayira Divyaprabandam.

A picture of Andal is kept in every Sri Vaishnava home, much in the way Meenakshi is kept in the home of Saivans.

Comment: You should cite some sources. Visit [guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/277), take a look at [help] for more information.